# ant: replace double empty line with single

Tags: ant, replace

I am trying to set up an script that goes through each file and replace all consecutive empty lines with just one empty line. something like:

```
aaa



bbb
```

converted to

```
aaa

bbb
```

so far I have:

```
<replace file="web.xml" value="">
            <replacefilter>
                <replacetoken>\n\n</replacetoken>
                <replacevalue>\n</replacevalue>
            </replacefilter>
        </replace>
```

but it isn't working at all

so far the only way is:

```
<target name="-remove-blank">
        <replaceregexp file="${basedir}/temp/WEB-INF/web.xml"
               match="(\r?\n)\s*\r?\n" 
               flags="g"
               replace="\1" 
        />
    </target>
```

but this deletes all blank lines whereas I need it to only delete when there are 2 or more consecutive blank lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <replaceregexp
  file="some.file"
  match="(${line.separator}){2}"
  replace="${line.separator}"
  flags="g"
 />
```

doesn't work.
**-- EDIT --**
given file

```
line1

line2

line3

line4


line5



line6
```

and using :

```
<replaceregexp
 file="foo.txt"
 match="^(${line.separator}){2,}"
 replace="${line.separator}"
 flags="mg"
/>
```

or when on windows (better use `${line.separator}` and let ant do the work):

```
<replaceregexp
 file="foo.txt"
 match="^(\r\n){2,}"
 replace="\r\n"
 flags="mg"
/>
```

works :

```
line1

line2

line3

line4

line5

line6
```

If lines contain whitespaces you have to use :

```
match="^(\s*${line.separator}){2,}"
```

or

```
match="^(\s*\r\n){2,}"
```